# Script could not be translated from: null in Trading view Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Does anyone know the reason for this error message?

thanks for listening.

```
@version=5
study("Spread Percentage", overlay=true)

// Define os pares de negociação
pair1 = security(tickerid, "D", close, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
pair2 = security(tickerid, "D", close, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

// Calcula o spread entre os pares
spread = pair1 - pair2

// Calcula o spread em porcentagem
spread_percent = (spread / pair1) * 100

// Desenha o spread em porcentagem no gráfico
plot(spread_percent, color = red, linewidth = 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, pair1=pair2, so whenyou try to plot, you give plot a null value, generating an error :

```
plot( 0 , color = red, linewidth = 2)
```

Comment: Got it. So how to capture the ids of the current peers?